# Zariski dense $K$-points for any non-trivial finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $V$ be a smooth $\mathbb{Q}$-variety. Assume that for any non-trivial finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ the $K$-points are Zariski dense in $V$. Must $V$ have a $\mathbb{Q}$-point then?

Comment: Remark: I think this is false if you replace $\mathbf{Q}$ with $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Varieties of the kind you consider have a $0$-cycle of degree $1$. Whether this (much weaker) condition implies the existence of a $\mathbb{Q}$-point is discussed in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33774/existence-of-zero-cycles-of-degree-one-vs-existence-of-rational-points . It is false in general, but is true for some families of varieties.

Comment: This is likely a very hard question, because we have very few methods for constructing rational points. Both a proof and a counterexample would have to do this.

Comment: @Uriya: I am probably being silly, but why does such a variety have a $0$-cycle of degree $1$?

Comment: @DamianRössler To see that there is a $0$-cycle of degree $1$ in the sense of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33774/existence-of-zero-cycles-of-degree-one-vs-existence-of-rational-points, take a quadratic extension $K/{Q}$ and a cubic Galois extension $L/{Q}$ with fixed embeddings into $\overline{ Q}$. Choose $x_1\in V(K)$ and $y_1\in V(L)$ and let $x_2,y_2,y_3\in V(\overline{Q})$ be their Galois conjugates (take $x_2=x_1$ if $x_1$ is fixed by $Gal(\overline{ Q}/{ Q})$ and likewise with $y_2,y_3$). Then $y_1+y_2+y_3-x_1-x_2$ is a $0$-cycle of degree $1$.

Comment: In general, having a $0$-cycle of degree $1$ is the same as having finite field extensions $K_1,\dots,K_t\supseteq \mathbb{Q}$ such that $V(K_i)\neq\emptyset$ for all $i$ and $\mathrm{gcd}([K_1:{\mathbb Q}],\dots,[K_t:{\mathbb Q}])=1$.

Comment: Note also that such varieties must have points everywhere locally (i.e. over all $\mathbf Q_p$, including $\mathbf Q_\infty = \mathbf R$), so the local-global principle fails. I'm not sure if this failure could be explained by the Brauer–Manin obstruction, but my feeling is that this obstruction would still exist over *some* nontrivial field extension.

Comment: @Uriya: thank you, that makes sense!